# Design Document Book?

Tags: document

I think I might be using the wrong words, however I am looking for books/website on pre-programming design. Not patterns but use cases, requirements etc. I would love a book that goes over all the preparation with the UML diagrams etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
As well if there is a better term to use then design document please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [one book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RYCMx6o47pMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=rational+unified+process&source=bl&ots=h-ioFZOaZd&sig=5-7z3Z4qPvgyLIewCbb3tjmqUPM&hl=en&ei=-rymTLj8MdCVOrXfyKkC&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)